# Data table + session = Shopping cart

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

GM everybody

i'm finding some issues in the implementation of my shopping cart

The query works but it doesn't store information in session.

Will i fix the query or the problem is the session ?

Here the code :

```
 Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("!aCommerce-ConnectionString!").ConnectionString

    ' Query SQL 
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Id,NomeProdotto, PrezzoProdotto, Quantità FROM aProdotti WHERE ID='" + Request.QueryString("ID").ToString + "' OR ID='" + Request.QueryString("ID").ToString + "'")

            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()

                Session("dt") = dt

                sda.Fill(dt)

                GridView1.DataSource = dt
                GridView1.DataBind()


            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: You should really use sql-parameters. Otherwise your "customers" will soon "buy" everything without paying. It's so easy to use them and don't concatenate strings to create your query, why still everyone does it?

Comment: So how can i change my code ? 

I'm newbye, this application is for learning coding, is not production use.

Anyway thank you !

Comment: Maybe a little less whitespace would improve readability.

Comment: You have removed some code, format it property and show all, starting from where you intialize the connection and ending with where you read the session. Because you have forgotten to show the most important, where you try to read the datatable from session but it's `Nothing`(is it?)

Comment: This is my code.
The connection String is taked by web.config 
What i've missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change you code to below

```
  Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

        Dim con As New SqlConnection()
        con.ConnectionString = constr
        con.Open()
        ' Query SQL 
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Id,PromoCode as NomeProdotto,PromoCodeMessage as  PrezzoProdotto, PromoCodeLimit as Quantità FROM EventPromocodetbl WHERE ID=" & Request.QueryString("ID").ToString & "", con)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Dim SessionDt As New DataTable()
                SessionDt = Session("dt")

                If Not SessionDt Is Nothing Then

                    If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                        Dim dr As DataRow
                        dr = SessionDt.NewRow()
                        dr("Id") = dt.Rows(0)("Id").ToString()
                        dr("NomeProdotto") = dt.Rows(0)("NomeProdotto").ToString
                        dr("PrezzoProdotto") = dt.Rows(0)("PrezzoProdotto").ToString
                        dr("Quantità") = dt.Rows(0)("Quantità").ToString

                        SessionDt.Rows.Add(dr)
                    End If

                    Session("dt") = SessionDt
                    GridView1.DataSource = SessionDt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                Else
                    Session("dt") = dt
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End If



            End Using
        End Using
```

Problem is you are assigning blank DatatTable to session and then you are filling that DataTable using DataAdapter fill method that is issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i've try your code, sda.Fill(dt) up to Session("dt") = dt . But it doesn't works ....

Comment: I add this too :

        Dim con2 As SqlConnection

        con2 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=NBK012\ARPASQL;Initial Catalog=aCommerceDB;Integrated Security=True")
        con2.Open()

....

Comment: The problem is that when i try to add the second item to the shopping cart, it replace the previous

Comment: In that case your code should be different that this. let me provide you that as well

Comment: This is the target of shopping cart and data table in session, thank you man , you're so kind !

Comment: The first item add successful to the table but when i come back on the previous page (where i have all the item ..), it give me an error : The operator '<>' nis not defined for type 'DataTable' e 'Nothing'.

Comment: check now friend

Comment: There are only a little bug, when i add the second item, it create a copy of the previous item .

Like this :


Id Nome PrezzoProdotto Quantità
1 i Phone 6s 600,99 1
1 i Phone 6s 600,99 1
7 Penna Bic Blu 0,2 1
7 Penna Bic Blu 0,2 1
16 Risma di fogli A4 3,2 1

Comment: Anyway a big thanks for your choice about spending lots of time with me.
Thanks again.